# How to set default form values for objects in Spring Boot : Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Alright, so im trying to learn Spring Boot and thymeleaf.  I have object worker that gets submitted and created, put in a database then the thymelaf page is updated to allow me to edit the worker I just created.  For the editing process I need to save the Worker object to the database with the same id so it will update it, my problem is that ID part. I dont want the user to input the id on the webpage but I want it to automatically be set.  The problem is, Spring Boot doesnt know which object im editing at the moment, but I have a feeling that thymeleaf knows, I just dont know how to go about it.

```
               <div th:each="woo : ${workers}">
                    <h1 th:text="${woo.getFirstName() + ' ' + woo.getLastName()}"></h1>
                    <form th:action="@{/updateWorker}" th:object="${worker}" method="post">
                        <div>First name:<input type="text" placeholder="John" name="firstName" th:value="${woo.firstName}"/></div>
                        <div>Last name: <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" name="lastName" th:value="${woo.lastName}"/></div>    
                        <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

And So I have this ^... The worker object has a variable id which I would like it to be automatically set to the id of object "woo" on form submission.  Any ideas on how to go about it?   Also any helpful critique on how I go about writing my thymeleaf template would be much appreciated, thanks.

edit: And so, just an hour later I figured out a partial solution,
`<button type="submit" class="btn update" name="id" th:value="${woo.id}">UPDATE</button>`, that allows me to set one value on button press.  Although what if I want to set a few default values in the future, this temporary solution I just found only allows one value, what if I want to set two or even three.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden input with ID value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${woo.id}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  Thats a cleaner way to do it than putting it in the button and I can use it for multiple values.  Im just thinking that that does seem pretty cheaty, anyone know if theres a more official way?  Or is that the most official way.  Other than that, awesome solution.

Comment: You can use  th:action="@{/updateWorker/${woo.id}}" to identify each Worker. To send all values you need to bind the Worker class attributes with the form inputs.